# Soft keyboard doesn't get hide programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am newbie to android and working on a demo for alert dialog box,I want to close the soft keyboard once one of the buttons from the alert is clicked.I have tried it programaticaly but keyboard remains open,can you pls help me for this issue,
**code**

```
  public void Show_Dialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                SwipeActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_albom_dialog, null);
        alertDialog.setView(layout);

        final InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Create",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        EditText txts = (EditText) layout
                                .findViewById(R.id.addAblum_edit);
                        hideSoftKeyboardDialogDismiss(SwipeActivity.this);
                        if(txts.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                            Add_album(txts.getText().toString());

                        } else {

                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SwipeActivity.this).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Name can't be emtpy");
                            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                                            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

                                        }
                                    });
                            alertDialog.show();

                        }
                        dialog.cancel(); // Your custom code
                    }
                });

        /* When negative (No/cancel) button is clicked */
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        hideSoftKeyboardDialogDismiss(SwipeActivity.this);
                        dialog.cancel();
                        //  finish();

                    }

                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText mSearchView) {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Rosu alin -Awesome ,you are great brother...i am having some more issues.can you help with that?

Comment: raise them on stackoverflow, leave them in a comment here? I will take a look

Comment: ok,brother.i am telling you,but i cant post question it says you can post every 90 mins..:(

Comment: Hi,I am explaining you my issue,I am having a listView and i am updating it on scroll,But when data comes and added to list,my list goes to first item ,any idea?

Comment: check so that you do not set the adapter again.
Make a new function in the adapter, where you add data to the data you already have, without needing to set the adapter on the list again

Answer (score 2):

```
dialog.setOnDissmissListener(){
   void onDismiss(){

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

   }
} 
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it the following way

```
final InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SwipeActivity.this).create();
                  alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                  alertDialog.setMessage("Name can't be emtpy");
                  alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                 inputManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(alertDialog.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                                 dialog.dismiss();

                          }
                  });
                 alertDialog.show();
```

Use your `alertDailog`'s current focus not your activity

Answer (score 1):

Actually there must be delay so use this code

```
  public static void hideSoftKeyboardDialogDismiss(final Activity activity) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =  (InputMethodManager) activity
                  .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                 if (null != activity.getCurrentFocus()) {
                  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity
                   .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                  }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks ashish,I have to call it? but where.can u help me little more brother..:)

Comment: when you are hiding dialog by dialog.dismiss

Comment: on its button clicks.there are two buttons "create" and "cancle". on both button i am dismising it.

Comment: please use this
dialog.dismiss();
 hideSoftKeyboardDialogDismiss(SwipeActivity.this);

Comment: if still don't work then please try with other values of delay like 100 in place of 1 in hideSoftKeyboardDialogDismiss